# Avoiding duplicate rows with many-to-many rails associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've seen a lot of many-to-many associations, but it seems that the common trend is that they end up using has_many :through relationships.

Let's say you have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_relationships
    has_many :relations, :through => :user_relationships
end

class UserRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :related_user, class_name: "User"
end
```

Given this type of relationship you end up setting the relationship up as follows:

```
user1.relations << user2
user2.relations << user1
```

Or this:

```
user1.user_relationships.build(related_user_id: 2)
user2.user_relationships.build(related_user_id: 1)
```

Resulting in rows in the join table looking like this:

```
user_id | related_user_id
1       | 2
2       | 1
```

So that when setting up the relation such as the above, you can see that the following can be accomplished

```
user1.relations.include? user2 = true
user2.relations.include? user1 = true
```

My question is: Is there a way to accomplish the above, or at least something similar to the above in speed, in Rails WITHOUT having to create 2 rows for every single two-way relationship and maintain the ability to see the relationship from both ends in an efficient manner, reducing the space complexity of creating this relationship by half...

Apologies if this is a noobie question, but I'm new to Rails, just starting to get the hang of things. It's easy to find out how to set these up, but I find it much harder to find out how to actually implement them in an efficient manner

Answer (score 0):

Here's (roughly) what I've done. I'm going to skip a ton of the detail, but am happy to share more if it's helpful. This may be heinous, so I'm curious about others' thoughts.

Essentially, I have a `Relationship` model something like:

```
module ActsAsRelatingTo
  class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :owner_id,                  presence: true
    validates :owner_type,                presence: true
    validates :in_relation_to_id,         presence: true
    validates :in_relation_to_type,       presence: true

    belongs_to  :owner,                   polymorphic: true
    belongs_to  :in_relation_to,          polymorphic: true

    acts_as_taggable
    acts_as_taggable_on :roles

  end
end
```

Then, I've created a acts_as_relating_to module (again, glossing over the details) that includes stuff like:

```
module ActsAsRelatingTo
  def acts_as_relating_to(*classes_array)

    # re-opens the class at run time so I can do things like add 
    # new instance methods on-the-fly
    class_eval do 

      before_destroy :tell_to_unrelate

      has_many :owned_relationships,
        as: :owner,
        class_name: "ActsAsRelatingTo::Relationship",
        dependent: :destroy

      has_many :referencing_relationships,
        as: :in_relation_to,
        class_name: "ActsAsRelatingTo::Relationship",
        dependent: :destroy

      # iterates through arguments passed in 'acts_as_relating_to' call
      # in the Person model, below.
      classes_array.each do |class_sym| 

        # This is a method created on-the-fly. So, when I call 
        # (in the Person model, below) 'acts_as_relating_to :people', 
        # then I get a method on each instance of 'Person' called 
        # 'people_that_relate_to_me. You can also create class methods
        # using `define_singleton_method`.
        #
        # The reason for doing all of this via the define_method 
        # is that it lets me create any number of 'things_i_relate_to'
        # methods on any class descending from ActiveRecord::Base 
        # (more on this in a bit). Which, if I understand it 
        # correctly, is how a lot of the ActiveRecord functionality gets
        # into a model in the first place. 
        define_method(class_sym.to_s + "_that_relate_to_me") do |options={}|
          ... some stuff
        end

        # Same as above, but know I'm defining a method called 
        # 'people_i_relate_to'
        define_method(class_sym.to_s+"_i_relate_to") do |options={}|
          ... some more stuff
        end

        # I can also create static methods and incorporate them in the 
        # 'Person' class. I just define them in modules (such as 
        # ActsAsRelatingTo::InstanceMethods and ActsAsRelatingTo::ClassMethods) 
        # and then either 'include' (for instance methods) or 'extend'
        # (for class methods) them.
        include InstanceMethods
        extend ClassMethods

      end
    end
  end
end

# Here, I'm telling ActiveRecord::Base to 'extend' this module. 
# That makes the 'acts_as_relating_to' method available in 
# any class that descends from ActiveRecord::Base.
ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsRelatingTo
```

Then, I can do something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Here, I am calling the method that I defined above, passing in
  # :people, :organizations, and :programs. This is exactly the 
  # sort of thing you do all the time when you say something like
  # 'has_one :foo', or 'belongs_to :bar'. 
  acts_as_relating_to :people, :organizations, :programs

  # Here, I am calling a method I have that builds on acts_as_relating_to,
  # but which I did not show, that creates administrative methods on 
  # the person so that I can say stuff like 'person.administrate organization'.
  # Or, 'organization.administrators'. 
  acts_as_administering :organizations, :programs

  ... 

end
```

So, if I have `person_1` and `person_2` and I have one relationship record where the `owner` is `person_1`, and the `in_relation_to` is `person_2`, then I can say `person_1.people_i_relate_to` and get back `person_2`. Or, I can say, `person_2.people_that_relate_to_me` and get back `person_1`.

I've also go an `acts_as_administering` module which builds on the `acts_as_relating_to` module and lets me do stuff like `person_1.administered_organizations` and `person_1.administered_programs`.

I've probably rattled on too long. Anyway, if it's interesting, I can say more.

Cheers!

Comment: very neat, a little over my head though, unfamiliar with ruby's reflection api and what class_eval does